# ExpressJS/Node/Socket.io Broadcast Message on every request

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a nodejs application in which I want to monitor every incoming request live on a webpage. I am trying to do this using socket.io. I have the following in my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000);

var usageLogger = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("GOT REQUEST !");
    var os = require("os"),
    cpus = os.cpus();

    var url = "URL: " + req.url + "\n" ;
    var urlTime = "Time: " + new Date().getTime() + "\n" ;

    var liveMessage = "<div><p><b>URL:</b> "+ req.url + "</p><p><b>Time: </b> " + new Date().getTime() + "</p></div>"

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.emit('news', liveMessage);
    });
}

app.use(usageLogger);
```

In my footer.jade file , I have the following:

```
.container
    .footer
        hr(style='margin: 30px 0 10px 0;')
        p &copy;&nbsp;
            a(href='#') Author
            |  2014

script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
script(type='text/javascript')
  |var socket = io();
  |socket.on('news', function(msg){
  |$('#messages').append(msg);
  |});


block footer
```

When I access any page, i only get the broadcast message, when i refresh the index page of the site. So for example, when I first access localhost:300, i can see the following:

URL: /
time: 0909234234

However, if I open a new tab and access localhost:3000/example, i have to refresh the first page to get the following view

URL: /
time: 0909234234

URL: /example
time: 0909234239

I am struggling to see why this does not automatically update without having to refresh the page. Any help me greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are emitting news when a request comes in. try broadcasting to all sockets.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani Thank you for getting back to me, I am fairly new to node and socket.io. Could you please provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani Thanks for the help. I figured it out. If you could post your answer below, I shall accept it. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code, for each coming request, when a socket connects, you emit `news` to that socket. what you want is, when a request comes in, emit `news` to all connected sockets.
you can do it in this way :

```
var usageLogger = function(req, res, next) {
   //do what you want
   ...
   io.sockets.emit('news', liveMessage);
}
```